# MS Access ADP Connection Error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010, windows-7-x64

I inherited a Microsoft Access 2000 ADP project a while back. For a long time it ran successfully on Windows XP, but we recently began upgrading to Windows 7 workstations. I was able to get the ADE file produced from building the ADP project working, however I cannot seem to open the ADP file without error.

The error message I am getting is below. The ADP project uses SQL Server 2008 R2 for the back end and I am using Access 2010 to open it on my Windows 7 (64 bit) workstation.

[image]

My connection string is below (with values substituted for the actual server and database):

```
PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;INTEGRATED SECURITY=SSPI;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=FALSE;INITIAL CATALOG=database;DATA SOURCE=server
```

Any assistance in debugging this error is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I don't quite understand. As I noted in the original question the database and server names have been substituted for security reasons.

Comment: From this error message, it seems that there is a connectivity *problem*. There is a SQL Server instance having the same name as this `DATA SOURCE=<sql server instance>` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Yes, the SQL instance and database exist that I am attempting to connect to. I can test the ODBC successfully as well as connect to the instance via SSMS. And as I noted, I am able to connect using the ADE, but not the ADP so the SQL Server itself shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Then I would follow the steps described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx). Also, if you try to create another ADP project you can connect to this SQL Server instance and DB ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Yes, I can access the database from a newly created ADP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was just a bad ADP file. I downloaded the same code from a different location and it worked.